# Private method in groovy is not private

Tags: groovy, private, private-members

```
class A {
    private def sayHello() {
       println "Anish"
    } 
 }

 def a_obj = new A()
 a_obj.sayHello()
```

output : `Anish`

Is there any way to protect `sayHello()` in groovy or am I missing something?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does 'private' mean in Groovy?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005700/what-does-private-mean-in-groovy)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There is [defect](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1875) on that in Groovy issue tracking system and that defect is still open.

Comment: Incredibly, still unfixed in version 4.  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-3010

Answer (score 10):

Searching for `[groovy] private` reveals:

[groovy call private method in Java super class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2834700/groovy-call-private-method-in-java-super-class)

[What does 'private' mean in Groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005700/what-does-private-mean-in-groovy)

[How to define private getter method in Groovy Bean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3819794/how-to-define-private-getter-method-in-groovy-bean)

It's not clear if it is a bug or by design, but it is going to get looked at again in Groovy 2.0

Comment: The behavior same in Groovy 2.0 as well.

Comment: @kadaj it's now scheduled to be looked at for groovy 3 ;-)

Answer (score 6):

You can use closures to achieve a similar effect, basically the same way you would do information hiding with Javascript.

```
package test

class FunctionTests {

    def privilagedObj = {

        def privVar = 'foo'

        def privateFunc = { x -> println "${privVar} ${x}"}

        return {x -> privateFunc(x) } 
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        def test = new FunctionTests().privilagedObj()

        test('bar')

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think its a bug in groovy that is fixed in groovy++.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/GROOVY-1875

Answer (score 1):

As other posts have mentioned, this may be a bug in Groovy. I've been sticking to a simple convention of prefixing private member names with a leading underscore (similar to Python) to denote that it's private which helps me understand from a client side perspective what I should be calling.